# Submit a form with input file using jquery malsup not working only in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

```
    // triggering input:file click via <a> tag click

    $('.upload_company_logo').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#addCompanyLogo input:file').click();
    });

    // main submit event

    $('#addCompanyLogo').submit(function() {
        $(this).unbind('submit').ajaxSubmit({    
            iframe: true,
            url : _ROOT + 'users/upload_company_logo',
            success: function (responseText, statusText) {   
                var response = $.parseJSON(responseText);
                if(statusText == 'success') {
                    var response = $.parseJSON(responseText);
                    $('.the_company_logo').attr('src', _ROOT + 'image/company_logo/' + response.tmp_name + '?t=' + (new Date()).getTime())
                } 
            }                         
        });
        return false;
    });

    // submitting form
    $('#addCompanyLogo input:file').on('change', function() {
       $('#addCompanyLogo').submit();
    });
```

I tried above code for **Upload Image via Ajax** and its working in all browsers just fine except IE, in IE its showing error `Access is Denied`.

One think to mention that, here the form `form#addCompanyLogo` is hidden and I'm triggering the `input:file` change event through a `<a>` tag click.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support submission of a form with file upload via onchange. It's a 'security' feature. Just change to triggering by direct click : )